# wrapping on using statement is throwing an error on api controller

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have below lines of code on my API controller which will return the file. This lines code code is working fine but I wanted to wrap these into the using statement to avoid the memory leaks. But if I do that, endpoint is not returning the file and I am getting exception "An unhandled exception was thrown by the application. System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed Stream."

```
                Stream memory = await _mySrv.GetDocMemoryStream(data);  
                var contentType = filename.GetContentType();
                return File(memory, contentType, "myfile.pdf");
```

Is it safe to leave the code like this, at least on the API controller? Will it handle by .NET core framework?

Comment: you can always use try->catch->finally  and put the closing statement in finally.

Answer (score 0):

If you define your `Stream` as `MemoryStream` you can then use `ToArray()` to put the stream content into the `File` result.

I am using similar code in one of my applications.

```cs
using (MemoryStream memory = await _mySrv.GetDocMemoryStream(data))
{ 
    var contentType = filename.GetContentType();
    
    return File(memory.ToArray(), contentType, "myfile.pdf");
}
```